# PostgreSQL division by zero when ordering column

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
SELECT wavelength, 
           (LEAD(wavelength) OVER (ORDER BY wavelength) - wavelength)/
           (LEAD(reflectance) OVER (ORDER BY wavelength) - reflectance) 
           AS reflectance
    FROM  grassland1
```

It shows error like this in Postgresql

```
ERROR:  division by zero
********** Error **********

ERROR: division by zero
SQL state: 22012
```

How i will correct this Pls anyone suggest me

Comment: You seem to be dividing by zero; fix that in your data perhaps? (In other words: `LEAD(reflectance) OVER (ORDER BY wavelength) - reflectance` returns `0`; it is not possible to divide by zero)

Comment: In my project there is no way of changing data, if anything comes in zero,i want to change it as 0 using CASE statement...if anyone knows about this case suggest me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT wavelength, 
       (LEAD(wavelength) OVER (ORDER BY wavelength) - wavelength)/
       (CASE WHEN (LEAD(reflectance) OVER (ORDER BY wavelength) - reflectance) = O THEN 1
        ELSE (LEAD(reflectance) OVER (ORDER BY wavelength) - reflectance) END)
       AS reflectance
FROM  grassland1
```

Comment: `coalesce` is to replaces `null` by first occurrence of a `non null` value. OP is not getting a `NULL` but `zero`.

Comment: You are right my friend,Tanks for your comment and i fix it now.

Comment: Aren't you changing the meaning of the output? "Can't have 0, oh well, just use 1" - what if all the other values come out between 0.2 and -0.2? Wouldn't that introduce completely bogus data?

Comment: yes it changed,because `n/1` can happens and the result is `n` but `n/0` meaning a big number which is out of range and cant be happened.i mean i just change the compile error to logic error which the programmer can solve it by debug.

Comment: `n/0` does not mean "*a big number*" it's an invalid mathematical operation

Comment: Yes sir,it's an invalid mathematical operation in computer,but in math it means http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_by_zero

Answer (score 2):

Use `case` then

```
SELECT wavelength,
case when (LEAD(reflectance) OVER (ORDER BY wavelength) - reflectance)=0 
     then 0
     else ((LEAD(wavelength) OVER (ORDER BY wavelength) - wavelength)/
          (LEAD(reflectance) OVER (ORDER BY wavelength) - reflectance))
end reflectance
FROM  grassland1
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon how you want to handle the situation when denominator expression `(LEAD(reflectance) OVER (ORDER BY wavelength) - reflectance)` evaluates to 0. Assuming you want divide to by 1 when it evaluates to 0, here is what you can do:

```
SELECT wavelength, 
           (LEAD(wavelength) OVER (ORDER BY wavelength) - wavelength)/
           (CASE WHEN (LEAD(reflectance) OVER (ORDER BY wavelength) - reflectance) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE (LEAD(reflectance) OVER (ORDER BY wavelength) END)
           AS reflectance
    FROM  grassland1
```